# Why is my header not being set on redirect?

Tags: node.js, express

I have an `express` route.  I set a `header` and a `cookie` and then I redirect.

```
router.get("/callback", async (req, res) => {
    res.cookie("token", token, {
        maxAge: COOKIE_EXPIRATION_MILLISECONDS
    });
    res.header("TEST", "HEADER");
    res.redirect("/test");
});
```

When I hit `/test`, `token` is set and available.  I do not have a `header` named `TEST`.  Why do I not have the `header`?  How do I pass the `header` through the `redirect`?

Comment: You can't instruct a client to pass a particular header with a subsequent request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your header is likely being sent with the response, but you won't see that header when the browser actually follows the redirect and then requests the new URL.  Browsers don't do that.  Remember, when you do `res.redirect()`, it sends a response with a 302 status and a location header.  The browser sees that 302 and reads the location header and then makes a new browser request to your server for the redirected location.  Headers from the previous response are NOT added to the new request for the redirected location.

The usual ways to pass data like this to a redirected requests are:

1. **Put it in the query string** for the redirected URL as a parameter.  Your server will then see that query string when the redirected requests comes in.
2. **Set a cookie.**  Your server can then look at the cookie when the redirected request comes in.
3. **Set data in a server-side session object** that can be accessed on the next request.  Your server can then look at the session when the redirected request comes in.

Only the first option above (query parameter) is entirely safe because the others can get confused about which request the data belongs to if there are other requests coming in from that same user.

Comment: is there any workaround for this situation? I want to implement something like this but the server and the redirect location are two different domains. the cookies are not going to work. also, I do not want to expose the data in the URL.

Comment: @ShawonKanji - Well, if the server and redirect location are two different servers, you HAVE to pass the data somehow.  I don't know of any way to do it other than in a query string unless you use some third party server as the holder of the data and pass some id in the query string that can be fetched from the third party server.  But, not sure why that would be any better.  There might be some schemes involving setting cookies on other domains, but many browsers may now be configured not to allow that.  Data in the query string is the most interoperable.

Comment: If you don't want the query string to stay visible, then the target host can redirect after it receives the query string and has the data to a more generic URL (keeping the received data locally in a cookie or server-side session).

Comment: Cookie is a kind of key to be used in the server to retrieve session values in the backend. How this is related to the headers in the frontend? I think the point 2 & 3 are the same because you cannot have session without a cookie. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @JRichardsz - A cookie can be used to contain the data that the front-end wants to see after the redirect.  The cookie does not have to be a session cookie.  It can just be a data cookie.  That's how options 2 and 3 are different.