# Cant assign a JWT to the header request

Tags: node.js, jwt

I have a problem using JWT. In the router responsible for the login page, on the post request, I assign a JWT for each login user, though I am not able to either send the token in the header of each page request after or actually save the token in the header. When I console log the token after each login and copy-paste it to the header in POSTMAN, it works fine, therefore i think this is my issue;

```
// generate a jwt for the login user
   const token = jwt.sign({_id: this._id, isAdmin: this.isAdmin}, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET, 
   {expiresIn: 1800});

// send back to the homepage with the token in the header (?)
    res.header('auth-token', token).redirect('/');
    console.log(token);
```

And after this assignment, I have tried to access an authenticated users page and it didn't work, I think because of the reasons I have mentioned.

This is my auth middleware, responsible for the authentication I add to the routers:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    const token = req.header('auth-token');
    if(!token){
        console.log('Access denied. No token provided.');
        return res.status(401).redirect('/login');
    }
    try{
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);
        console.log(decoded);
        req.user = decoded;
        console.log('Access approved.');
        next();
    }
    catch(ex){
        console.log('Invalid token');
        res.status(403).redirect('/');
    }
}
```

I have no idea what am I missing. Tried to find a solution but nothing worked for me.
Thanks to the helpers!

Comment: Can you add more details regarding your router?

Comment: Try using Cookie (`res.cookie(...)`) instead of the header. Your client doesn't "remember" the JWT after the redirect. Using Cookies tels the client to resend the data on each request to the domain.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my header not being set on redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46133557/why-is-my-header-not-being-set-on-redirect)

Comment: well, can u explain how do i do the first solution there?